# overloading virtual operator -> ()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, virtual, overriding

This is just an experiment code.

```
struct B
{
  virtual B* operator -> () { return this; }
  void foo () {} // edit: intentionally NOT virtual
};

struct D : B
{
  virtual D* operator -> () { return this; }
  void foo () {}
};

int main ()
{
  B &pB = *new D;
  pB->foo();  // calls B::foo() !
}
```

I know that `operator` has to be called using object or reference; thus in above case does reference `pB` still resolute to the object of `B` ?
Though it will not be practical, but for curiosity, is there any way to invoke `D::operator ->` through `pB` ?

Comment: Does not make sense to have operator-> virtual when you want to have foo() virtual.

Comment: I might be missing something here, but what's wrong with just making `void foo()` virtual? The `operator->()` is completely pointless in this situation, especially since it just returns `this`.

Comment: @In silico, I agree, This is just an experiment code to learn what happens when `operator ->` becomes `virtual`. I have edited my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it *is* invoking `D::operator->`, but the return value is being treated as a `B*`, so `B::foo()` is being called.

This is an artifact of how **covariant return types** behave.

Answer (score 2):

`pB` is of type `B&`. Hence any method (such as `operator->`) invoked on it will get the signature in `B`, therefore `pB.operator->()` will return a `B*`. Of course, because it's virtual, the actual implementation in `D` is used. The important thing is that the return type is defined by the type of the pB variable.

So, our `operator->` has returned a `B*`, and therefore invoking `foo()` proceeds as with any other `B*`.

Comment: This answer is not new, but I thought it might be useful to try to expand a little further on the logic.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter which operator it invokes (which in this case is probably `D::operator->`), what matters is the `this`. In this case the `this` pointer is of type `B*`, so the `foo` call is dereferenced to `B::foo`. If it was `virtual` - it would work correctly, but you intentionally didn't make it `virtual`...

Answer (score 1):

Virtual member functions are invoked in accordance with the *dynamic* type of the object used in the call. Non-virtual member functions are invoked in accordance with the *static* type of the object used in the call.

Function `foo` is not virtual. That means that it is always called in accordance with *static* type of the object. The static type in this case is `B` (since the declared type of the result of `B::operator ->` is `B *`), so `B::foo` is called.